# implementing skrollr on website + other bugs

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, skrollr

I am developing GoldenStateLiquidation.com but have developed plenty of bugs in trying to put many projects together to form something beautiful. I put skrollr.js and skrollr.min.js inside js folder, called that in the header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.js"></script>
```

and my HTML looks like:

```
<section id="slide-3" class="homeSlide">
    <div class="bcg" data-top="background-position: 50% 0px;" data-center="background-position: 50% 100px;" data-anchor-target="#slide-3">
        <div class="hsContainer">
            <div class="hsContent" data-center="bottom: 200px; opacity: 1" data-top="bottom: 0; opacity: 0" data-anchor-target="#slide-3 h2"></div>
            <?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>
            <?php if( get_option( 'hathor' )){ ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="slider">
                    <?php get_template_part( ''.$slides=o f_get_option( 'slider_select', 'nivo'). ''); ?>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'dummy/dummy', 'nivo'); ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <?php }?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is me trying to implement parallax Skrollr with the already-given Hathor theme nivo.slider.
I have many other bugs maybe you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement srkollr.js at the end of your html, just before closing body-tag.
just use following code...

```
<script src="js/skrollr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
skrollr.init({
forceHeight: false
});
}
</script>
```